# Python / Sqlite / phone number

Tags: python, sqlite

создаю таблицу через model в sqlite3 подскажите для поля номера телефона какой выбирать лучше Field если номера могут быть 
+380630000000
+38(063)0000000
+38-063-000-00-00``
+38 063 000 00 00

Comment: Перед занесением в базу приводите номера к одному формату, например, удаляйте из него все символы кроме + и цифр. Кст, а как в sqlite3 создавать таблицу через модуль (не нашел тут: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)?

Comment: *удаляйте из него все символы кроме + и цифр* Кроме **ведущего +** и цифр.

Comment: Вот тут все описано https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/intro/tutorial02.html просто создаю class в model.py и потом миграция подтягивает автоматом в базу

Comment: [`django-phonenumber-field`](https://pypi.org/project/django-phonenumber-field/)